# navbar links not working in mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not able to go the sections I want to go after clicking the navbar links, that is , suppose I click on about link on the navbar, it does not scrolls down to the about section of the page. this is the link to my website - https://xenodochial-spence-432cef.netlify.app/ the navbar links work perfectly fine in desktop.

this is the javascript for opening the navbar in mobile devices

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");

  links.forEach((link) => {
    link.classList.toggle("fade");
  });
});

window.onscroll = () => {
  this.scrollY > 20
    ? nav.classList.add("sticky")
    : nav.classList.remove("sticky");
}



this is the css for navbar in desktop
```

```css
.nav-wrapper{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.5);
}
.nav-wrapper.sticky{
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo{
    font-size: var(--heading-font);
    font-family: var(--logo-font);
    font-weight: 800;
    
}

.logo .gobble{
    color: var(--heading-color);
}
.logo .up{
    color: white;
}
.hamburger{
    display: none;
}
.menu-items{
width: 800px;
    
}
.nav-links{
  
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-items ul li a {
    color: white;
    
    text-decoration: none;
   font-family: var(--common-font-family);
   font-size: var(--nav-font);
   font-size: 16px;
}
.menu-items ul li a:hover{
  color: var(--heading-color);
 
}
.menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
  }
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 6;
    transition: stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1),
      stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
  .line1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
    stroke-width: 6;
  }
  .line2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
    stroke-width: 6;
  }
  .line3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
    stroke-width: 6;
  }
  .opened .line1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset: -134;
    stroke-width: 6;
  }
  .opened .line2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1 60;
    stroke-dashoffset: -30;
    stroke-width: 6;
  }
  .opened .line3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset: -134;
    stroke-width: 6;
  }

this css is for mobile devices

 @media screen and (max-width: 1050px){
.nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--heading-color);
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -30%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -30%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -30%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1400px at 90% -30%);
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
 
  .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }
  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo"><span class="gobble">Gobble</span> <span class="up">Up.</span></div>
            <div class="menu-items">
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#our-menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#chef">Chef</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#reservation">Reservation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#speciality">Speciality</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#testimonial">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <button class="menu hamburger"
                    onclick="this.classList.toggle('opened');this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', this.classList.contains('opened'))"
                    aria-label="Main Menu">
                    <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                        <path class="line line1"
                            d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058" />
                        <path class="line line2" d="M 20,50 H 80" />
                        <path class="line line3"
                            d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I checked the netlify link and I think you have fixed the issue because the navbar links work totally fine now. Let me know if there is still anything left I can help you with.

Comment: @Triaro I fixed it by changing the js code but i still dont understand why  my navbar was hiding the fact that the page has scrolled down

Answer (score 0):

What you may need to do is hide the NAV bar when the user clicks on one of the links. On my mobile device it works, the NAV bar just hides the fact it has moved

Maybe changing This:

```
hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");

  links.forEach((link) => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
    link.classList.toggle("fade");
  });
});
```

Comment: actually i wanted to know why does it hide the fact that the page has moved down

Comment: For me it did not look like the page had scrolled down because the NAV bar was still showing. But, on closing the NAV bar I could see that the page had moved. Tested on an iphone

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and found below solution.

```
window.onload = function () {
  $('.site-mobile-menu-body li').click(function () {
           if ($(this).find('a').attr('href') != '#') {
               window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
           }
       });
   }
```

Comment: Hi, please explain how this can address the problem... I don't understand